# python returning a list from a recursive method

Tags: python, recursion, binary-tree, preorder

Im using a binary tree described in this book
[problem solving with algorithms and data structures](http://interactivepython.org/LpOMZ/courselib/static/pythonds/Trees/implementation.html)

```
class BinaryTree:
    def __init__(self,rootObj):
        self.key = rootObj
        self.leftChild = None
        self.rightChild = None
```

There is already a preorder traversal method defined as follows.

```
def preorder(tree):
    if tree:
        print(tree.self.key)
        preorder(tree.getLeftChild())
        preorder(tree.getRightChild())
```

I just want to add a return value of the list of nodes visited. So I can do something like

```
for i in preorder(tree):
    etc...
```

Im having trouble returning a list from a recursive method. The recursion stops as soon as it hits the 'return' I've tried variations using

```
return [tree.self.key] + preorder()
```

Or

```
yield ...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What error are you getting? Is it something about concatenating None and list?

Comment: 1). It appears that `preorder()` is a helper function and not actually a method of the `BinaryTree` class, so calling it a method is a little confusing. 2). If `tree` is an instance of `BinaryTree`, then `tree.self.key` is wrong. 3). In Python you rarely need getter (or setter) methods, you just access the attributes directly. Eg, `preorder(tree.leftChild)`.

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure you want `tree.self.key` and not simply `tree.key` when you print?

Otherwise, a solution with [`yield from`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/) (Python 3.3+):

```
def preorder(tree):
    if tree:
        yield tree
        yield from preorder(tree.getLeftChild())
        yield from preorder(tree.getRightChild())
```

Or with simple `yield`:

```
def preorder(tree):
    if tree:
        yield tree
        for e in preorder(tree.getLeftChild()):
            yield e
        for e in preorder(tree.getRightChild()):
            yield e
```

Note that using `yield` or `yield from` transforms the function into a [generator function](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=yield#yield-expressions); in particular, if you want an actual list (for indexing, slicing, or displaying for instance), you'll need to explicitly create it: `list(preorder(tree))`.

If you have a varying number of children, it's easy to adapt:

```
def preorder(tree):
    if tree:
        yield tree
        for child in tree.children:
            yield from preorder(child)
```

Comment: Since you're directly accessing `tree.key`, you might as well use `preorder(tree.leftChild)` and `preorder(tree.getRightChild)`. In addition, you should mention that to get the list of nodes this way you'd need to do something like `nodes = list(preorder(tree))` or `nodes = [node for node in preorder(tree)]`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about the list.
As for your other point, I'm accessing `tree.key` because I don't want to guess if there is a `getKey()` method but I believe that OP's `tree.self.key` might be faulty. There is already a comment about the lack of need of getters and setters in Python but here it's really besides the point.

Comment: I mentioned showing how to create a list because of the title of the question. Also note that it should be `print tree.key`, not `yield tree.key` — the OP wants a list of nodes, not one with a mixture of nodes and keys.

Comment: There was no nodes but only keys (by induction: `preorder` only yielded `tree.key` or what `preorder` yielded). But indeed OP seems to want a list of nodes so I've edited for `yield tree`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to actually *return* a value from the recursive function (currently, it's just printing values). And you should build the list as you go, and maybe clean the code up a bit - something like this:

```
def preorder(tree):
    if not tree:
        return []
    # optionally, you can print the key in this line: print(self.key)
    return [tree.key] + preorder(tree.leftChild) + preorder(tree.rightChild)
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the replies. I'm using python v3.4, I didn't get the yield expression working, Im still a bit lost between iterators and generators... Anyway this 'if not tree return empty list' fixes the problem I was having with 'can not + NoneType'

Answer (score 1):

You can add second argument to `preorder` function, something like

```
def preorder(tree, visnodes):
    if tree:
        visnodes.append(tree.self.key)
        print(tree.self.key)
        preorder(tree.getLeftChild(), visnodes)
        preorder(tree.getRightChild(), visnodes)

...
vn = []
preorder(tree, vn)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply return a concatenated list for each recursive call, which combines the current key, the left subtree and the right subtree:

```
def preorder(tree):
        if tree:
            return ([tree.key] + preorder(tree.getLeftChild()) +
                    preorder(tree.getRightChild()))
        return []
```

For an n-ary tree:

```
def preorder(tree):
    if tree:
        lst = [tree.key]
        for child in tree.children:
            lst.extend(preorder(child))
        return lst
    return []
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply works perfectly. Just wandering if its not a binary tree how can I loop over all the children e.g.
    def preorder(tree):
        if tree:
            return [tree.key] + [preorder(child, msg) for child in tree.children]

Comment: @DamianSavage Yeah, but using list comprehension here would lead to a list of lists, since each ```preorder``` call returns a list. You can use a loop to to achieve this. I'll update my answer with that.

Comment: Instead of explicitly looping you can use [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum): `return sum((preorder(child) for child in tree.children), [tree.key])`.